# Undefined complexType 'java.lang.Object' is used as a base for complex type extension

Tags: android, layout, visual-studio-2015

I have very simple layout in .axml source file in AndroidApp.
I use this layout to add dynamic TextViews and Buttons. Application works correct.

Even though I get a warning (Line 6, Column 8): Undefined complexType 'java.lang.Object' is used as a base for complex type extension.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:x="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    x:orientation="horizontal"
    x:layout_width="match_parent"
    x:layout_height="match_parent"
    x:id="@+id/mainLayout"/>
```

Comment: found any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 7):

This is a common problem in VS 2017 and Xamarin and many people are complaining about it.

[Visual studio 2017 Intellisense error](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92988/visual-studio-2017-intellisense-error)

I think It's a bug, waiting for Microsoft to release a bugfix for it.

Comment: found any solution to this problem ?

Comment: No not yet, I'm using Android studio for now.