# Visual Studio 2017 Deployment Error : Undefined ComplexType java.lang.Object is used as a base for complex type extension

Tags: android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

Today ,I install *Visual Studio 2017* ,Started creating android app .
While building the app ,It's getting Build Properly .But ,when i am running it is giving following deployment issue :

> Undefined ComplexType java.lang.Object is used as a base for complex
>   type extension

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

- Following Error coming while running the app :

[image]

**Update :**
Right now from **Android SDK Manager** ,I updated the packages also .But same issue persists .

Any one if can explain the issue and provide the perfect solution ,Thanks in advance .

***NOT Duplicate As ,***

1. My project is compiling properly .
2. When i execute/run ,It gets
       deployment Error .Earlier it was giving compilation issue .I rectify
       it but rounded with Deployment issue .
3. Tried solution provided out there and other forum also ,Yet struggling to create first
   android app .

Comment: The screenshot you attached of the layout. This is a normal Android .XML layout file, while the compiler is blaming you about a main.AXML file, which is another format with different syntax. Maybe the compiler is trying to convert the android widgets like LinearLayout to the base java objects. Re-check if you didn't any mistakes using the corrects files

Comment: @MatPag ..  yeh it's a very simple startup test program i had created .Just to check if everything good to go .But Deployment error found after sucessfull Build .. I just rechecked everything but issue resist .

Comment: Have you tried to start your project with the sample provided by Xamarin [here](https://www.xamarin.com/getting-started/android) and [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/)?

Comment: Yeh @MatPag ,Just now download and tried same ,there was some build issue .I changed target version ,get resolved build .
But finally when executed ,Get hacked with same deployment issue .
Issue still retained !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined complexType 'java.lang.Object' is used as a base for complex type extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351316/undefined-complextype-java-lang-object-is-used-as-a-base-for-complex-type-exte)

Comment: Hey ,@Pavel .Thanks for taking interest but the issue is i get through all the compilation issues.But the deployment issue is getting me bound to move forward .