# ScrollView undefined complexType in visual studio using xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android, scrollview

I'm using  to make my view scrollable.

But I'm getting this error and cannot figure out why.

```
Undefined complexType 'java.lang.Object' is used as a base for complex type extension.
```

[image: ScrollView]

Any insight to why this is happening or a solution would be great. Thanks

Comment: Please provide some more code samples to narrow down the problem. Furthermore is this a warning or an error? If it's a warning it might be this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351316/undefined-complextype-java-lang-object-is-used-as-a-base-for-complex-type-exte

Comment: Solved, thank you. It's a warning, and it seems like it is a bug with visual studio?

Comment: Apparently so - but the developers know about it so I expect a fix. If you don't mind I post my comment as an answer for you to accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a known problem in VS 2017, which should be fixed soon.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92988/visual-studio-2017-intellisense-error